# How do I count multiple specific values for each item?

Tags: mysql, date, count, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a query that will group items by description, and then count that item for the past 3 months, with each month having its own column. Ultimately I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

```
    +-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+
    | Description | This Month | Last Month | The Previous Month |
    +-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+
    | Item_1      |          4 |          3 |                  5 |
    | Item_2      |          3 |          0 |                  2 |
    | Item_3      |          1 |          3 |                  5 |
    +-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Could you specify more info? Like DB tool, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    "Description",
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() THEN 0
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END CASE
    ) AS "This month",
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 0
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END CASE
    ) AS "Last month",
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH THEN 0
        WHEN "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END CASE
    ) AS "The previous month"
FROM Items
WHERE "Date" > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY "Description"
```